# How can I find out the pair of tokens that were swapped using web3.py?

Tags: web3js, bsc

I have TxHash and TxInput. How i can get names tokens and amount?

I tried searching for information on how to do this and found a similar solution:

```
from web3 import Web3
import json
bsc = 'https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))

# uniswap factory address and abi = pancakeswap factory
uniswap_factory = '0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73'  
uniswap_factory_abi = json.loads("[{super long abi}]")
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=uniswap_factory, abi=uniswap_factory_abi)

#pancakeswap router abi
panRouterContractAddress = '0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E'
panabi = "[{super long abi}]"
contractbuy = web3.eth.contract(address=panRouterContractAddress, abi=panabi)

result = 
web3.eth.get_transaction("0x77c5949df82ce8625d9e578fc696bc7264c99dbea4f763ce1fcdbe59dac5f029")
#tx_json = Web3.toJSON(result)
#json_obj = json.loads(tx_json)

#returns a tupple packed in these two objects
func_obj, func_params = contractbuy.decode_function_input(result["input"])

print(func_params)
```

but I don't understand where to get the contract ABI

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the contract ABI using the following command:

```
solc <filename>.sol --abi
```